# Problems with using GMap.NET for Google Maps. Unable to connect to the internet and errors CS0246

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, google-maps

I am newbie in C#. I need to make a simple Winform app that using Google Maps and I decided to use [GMap.NET](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) control. I does everything like in [this guide, provided on GMap.NET official site](http://www.independent-software.com/gmap-net-tutorial-maps-markers-and-polygons/). But (!) I don't found any kind of readmy for it. Also, I have 2 problems:
1) App can not connect to the internet (so, I can see only this:

[image: Window]
[image: No connection]
)

2) I have an error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PointLatLng' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) for some commands, why? I am confused, everything is connected, referenced etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you behind a proxy ?

If so, did you configure it like this :

```
System.Net.WebProxy myProxy=new System.Net.WebProxy(“XXXXXXX.com”,3128);
GMap.NET.MapProviders.GMapProvider.WebProxy = myProxy;
```

Comment: Oh, thnx, 1 problem resolved, dat was a proxy  for some types of connection, I even doesn't realized it before you said!
So, where I can find a list of commands or even smth, any references for GMap? Also, how can I resolve the second problem? I try everything, but nothing changed.

Comment: For your second question, did you forgot a `using` ?

Comment: using GMap.NET;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers;
using GMap.NET.WindowsForms.ToolTips;

Sometimes it giving error anyway :(
Where I need to use System.Net.WebProxy, inside of GMap control?

Comment: Oh, and where I can find documentation?

Comment: Now I can not resolve the "'GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl' does not contain a definition for 'SetCurrentPositionByKeywords' and no extension method 'SetCurrentPositionByKeywords' accepting a first argument of type 'GMap.NET.WindowsForms.GMapControl' could be found" problem :( Aaaaah, I am sooo baad :(

Comment: Indeed, I just tested, and they changed the method name with `g.SetPositionByKeywords("Maputo, Mozambique");`

Comment: Oh, I love you! How you understood this? So, last thing I can not figure out: is it possible to resize the GMap control inside the app? Is it possible to change a view mods inside the app? And is it possible to to calculate the area of the figure you draw on the map? And where I can find a full list of opportunities of GMap?

Comment: Oh, and why there's so little amount of detailes on the map? Can I connect Google Map to the project?

Comment: Check this link for more information and demo solutions : http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/documentation .

On a side note, auto-completion gives you the listing of all events and methods. I found the correct one this way.

The sample you took uses BingMaps as the provider. Just write `GMap.NET.MapProviders`, add a `.` and choose from the listing the provider you want/need.

Comment: new GMapPolygon(points, "mypolygon"); - how to use it? I still can't find a listing of all events and method :(  Oh, sorry for being annoying.

Comment: And how can I open menu like that: http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20generate%20static%20map%20image